# What does "fell out of use with Shakespeare" suggest?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> It doesn’t matter if it was common in 1400 but fell out of use with Shakespeare.

Does "fell out of use with Shakespeare" mean that "when Shakespeare died, that word also fell out of use because it was in his works the remnants of word were seen and along with him the word also perished? I doubt the latter's plausibility on the ground that Shakespeare was not present in 1400 but still am in want of confirmatiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Shakespeare is likely being used here as a reference date. When you say Shakespeare, they might not know exactly when he was around, but have a general sense of the historical period you are talking about. And using date alone, say 1600 AD, also may not immediately click with readers. So by saying "fell out of use with Shakespeare" would mean (without further context) that by Shakespeare's time, whatever the phrase was referring to was already dying out and he was the last major writer to use it.

Comment: I would say not needing to be dying out in shakespears lifetime, but it stopped being used in Tudor/Stuart times.  It is really archaic

Answer (score 1):

The article is referencing **the development of the English language**. In 1400 the English used would have been **Middle English** not what we referred to today as **Early Modern English**.

Modern English is often dated from the Great Vowel Shift (a major change in the pronunciation of the English language), which took place mainly during the 15th century. However by the time of the **arrival of William Shakespeare (mid-late 16th century). Modern English was fairly well established and clearly recognisable**. In 1604 the first English dictionary was published. Modern English in relative terms has changed little since that time.

> "**During the 15th century, a huge amount of change affected English pronunciation, spelling, grammar, and vocabulary**, so that Shakespeare would have found Chaucer almost as difficult to read as we do. But between Jacobean times and today the changes have been very limited.

---

**To summarise**  "fell out of use with Shakespeare" means that By Shakespearean times the language had evolved (from Middle English to Modern English) and many old words were no longer used.

---

> **Definition of Modern English** is conventionally defined as the English language since about 1450 or 1500. [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/modern-english-language-1691398)
>
> **Middle English** (ME) [Open Uni](https://www.open.edu/openlearn/history-the-arts/culture/english-language/old-english-modern-english) (conventionally dated c.1100-1500)